# How do I access flags menu on textures in Godot 3.2.2?

Tags: godot

In previous versions of Godot, you could access the texture flags by doing

[image]

Now in the newest version, 3.2.2, the flags menu is nowhere to be found.

[image]

Where do I find it in the new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flags menu is now in the "imports" menu:

[image: The scene tree tab in Godot's default UI layout, with an arrow pointing toward the import tab next to it]

You have to select the image itself in the file system:

[image: The FileSystem widget in Godot's UI, with "icon.png" highlighted.]

And there they are:

:[image: The Import tab, opened in Godot's default UI layout, showing the import properties for icon.png; visible are compression methods and flags.]

Comment: I'm a total amateur. When I click reimport, does the new settings apply to all sprites that are using the image as a texture? Or do I have to reimport for every single sprite?

Comment: It applies to every sprite that uses the image as a texture.